Scratch files have disappeared on Android Studio upgrade
I had recently updated my Android Studio to Jellyfish from Hedgehog via Jetbrains toolbox on my mac. And now all my scratch files that I had are now disappeared. Is there any way where I could retrieve that?
I've done these upgrades before but it retains the previous configurations but this time it looked like a fresh install where nothing was migrated. Even all the plugins that I had installed were gone. That is however a minor problem as I can reinstall it anytime unlike the scratch files content that I refer to frequently is gone. Is this a common issue people face when upgrading to AS Jellyfish?

We can have this closed.
I got the scratch files from this location
/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2023.1
